# C++ in Visual Studio 2015: Manually pass in command line args

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, console-application

In visual studio you can specify in

"Project Properties > Debugging > Command Arguments"

the arguments you want to pass in. But I want to be able to change this manually so I can run different arguments and test my code. Is there a way to open the console and pass in arguments like you normally would in a unix shell?

./myProg arg1 arg2

Having to go into the properties and change every time is annoying.

Thanks!

Comment: Going X-Y on you here. Separate the code logic that relies on those command line arguments from the arguments parser. then either call the core logic from another arguments parser that allows you to specify the arguments while running or build a loop that calls the core logic over and over again with a pool of different command line arguments.

Comment: ***Is there a way to open the console and pass in arguments like you normally would in a unix shell?*** You can run your program from the command line directly. I always have several `cmd.exe` windows open during development. However remember that if you do so the default folder will be the same as the exe instead of the project folder.

Comment: A second option is a visual studio addon that lets you save more than 1 set of command lines and switch between the saved: http://n0n4m3.x10host.com/2014/03/11/cliargsmadeeasy2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure specifically with how you'd like to open the console, like what the intended result here is. I could interpret this a few ways.

1. You can run your application from an external command prompt set to the binary directory with any args you want, but the issue is that you would have to attach your debugger if you needed to do debugging. You could switch to console-based debugging or you could introduce a console read in order to attach the debugger.
2. In later versions of Windows, holding shift and right clicking in Explorer yields an `Open command window here` option. This makes it quick and easy to open up a command prompt. You can right click a C++ project and `Open Folder in File Explorer`. This'll get you most of the way there.
3. If you want, you could specify a special sentinel arg that allows you to interactively populate commandline args within the program. Either that or if there are expected to be args and there are none, you could assume that means interactive mode.
4. Using [`cmd /c`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx), you might be able to come up with some really tricky things. Using batch files or all sorts of craziness to populate args. You could combine this with build steps etc. to produce output that batch files read. The sky is the limit.

I don't know specifically what sort of thing you were after, but hopefully this enumerates some things that might be of help.